# Is using an enum to differentiate different events in an observer pattern plausible if it's on a small scale?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, observer-pattern

I need to collect statistics during an algorithm. To not mix the statistical code with the algorithm code too much, I'd like to decouple that by publishing "statistical events" that can then be consumed where appropriate.

For that I'd like a lightweight implementation using an Enum instead of an interface.
Code speaks more than a thousand words, so let me quickly whip up an example:

```
public class ObjectThatHasEvents {

    private Map< StatisticEvent, List<Consumer> > registeredObserver = ...

    public enum StatisticEvent{
        OPTION_1_HAPPENED,
        OPTION_2_HAPPENED,
        IMPLICIT_VALUE_THAT_NEEDS_TO_BE_RECORDED_FOR_STATISTICS,
      ...
    }

    public void registerObserver(StatisticEvent event, Consumer callback) {
         //add the consumer to the map on the correct event
    }

    private void triggerEvent(StatisticEvent event, Integer valueForConsumption) 
    {
        registeredObserver.get(event).forEach(i -> i.consume(valueForConsumption)
    }

    //all the other necessary stuff here...

}
```

Advantage: It's quite easy to add a new event, you add a new eventType to the enum, publish it where appropriate, and register to it somewhere else in the code.

Disadvantage: I'm banking on the fact that the callback is always a single param consumer. If a situation arises where that ain't the fact, the whole system could come crashing down or require serious hacking. I *might* be able to cheat this a bit with generic callbacks, but that would require some thought, ugly hacks and probably is non-obvious.

The alternative is having an statistical interface just for this class, that needs to then be implemented with all methods etc., possibly overswarming the class with many many methods that basically always do the same thing.

Is this approach viable, or am I missing something entirely?

Answer (score 3):

If we remove the context/meaning and just look at the code, yes, this is a valid way of doing it.

**However**, what you're trying to do is to take a shortcut by trying to bypass the typing system that events tend to rely on. What you're trying to do here is no different from using `object` as method parameter types so you could pass any kind of object into it. That's more often than not a bad idea.

But this is a purely semantical argument. If we were talking about a strictly defined event, which just happens to contain an enum as data (rather than to define the event type itself), that would be perfectly fine. For example a `PlayerDrawsCard` event where the `CardSuit` is an enum.

> Advantage: It's quite easy to add a new event, you add a new eventType to the enum, publish it where appropriate, and register to it somewhere else in the code.

Continually having to expand an enum is an [OCP](https://stackify.com/solid-design-open-closed-principle/) violation.

Not that enums are never allowed to be changed after you've created them - but relying on the continual expansion of an enum to keep the code working is just not a great idea. It leads to "switch branching" which in itself is a further OCP violation.

Slightly oversimplified, OCP states that when you add a feature, you should only be adding new classes/code, not changing old classes/code to account for the new things.

> The alternative is having an statistical interface just for this class, that needs to then be implemented with all methods etc., possibly overswarming the class with many many methods that basically always do the same thing.

If they were doing the same thing, the enum would be irrelevant and you would just be using `StatisticalEvent`. If it's the same handling, there's no use to having any further distinction between event types.

It's very easy to overgeneralize. Just because some things are somewhat similar does not mean they are the same, or that they can easily be abstracted. Sometimes, the cost of abstraction is higher than the gains from abstracting. It's hard to make that judgment here, given that we don't really see much of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what an event means to you. If it is just a signal, enum should be fine. Otherwise you may implement an abstract Event or Interface and concrete Events. With that adding a new Event type is as simple as creating a sub class and each Event type may contain different type of data you want to send to the observer.